# Polymer.dom(element).innerHTML not working

Tags: javascript, dom, polymer, polymer-1.0

I have html in text representation...something like this:

```
<link rel="import" href="../resources/widget/my-footer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../resources/widget/my-header.html">
<link rel="import" href="../resources/widget/my-booking-confirmation.html">
<my-booking-confirmation> //and some styles and markup'
```

And I'm trying to use Polymer DOM API, but

```
Polymer.dom(root).innerHTML = upperMarkdown
```

not working. When I call root.innerHTML I'm getting only first element from html string:

```
<link rel="import" href="../resources/widget/my-footer.html">
```

It is a bug? I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: when are you calling it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm doing somethime like that, after an iron-ajax call, I get an entire html file,

```
if (response != null && response != undefined) { //iron-ajax response
  var documentBody = response.querySelector('body'); //select body of html file
  if (documentBody != null && documentBody != undefined) { //body's validations
      Polymer.dom(this.$.content).innerHTML = documentBody.innerHTML; //add content
  }
}
```

Honestly, I dont know how it works, but I think there is a clue how you must do that. Files content's (this file only has a tag to refer another Polymer element) is added to my page, so I think this works. Obviously I need more research to fully understand how it  works, but I think this may help you. Sorry for my english!

Answer (score 1):

I am doing this which appears to work:

```
Polymer.dom(elm).node.innerHTML = "<div>something</div>";
```

The confusing part was the fact that the 'node' property is there and what it's for. This needs to be documented better, I think, and the question remains why the innerHTML at the element itself doesn't work, but only the 'node' property does.